# JavaScript / GoogleApps find every cells in table that contain 28 characters

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MUjFiLL1a8-1LELqdaV-8G1terhItZA4JD9LQD02hxo/edit) document and am not sure if it is even possible. I want to identify each instance of 28 characters in the document using JavaScript. I'm thinking there are two ways to go about it, but not sure how to proceed.

1. Is there a way to only look at a certain cell in every table in the document
2. Is there a way to search an entire document for every string of 28 characters without space?

My end goal is to append that to a url and then import an image from the create URL. Currently the script I have can do all of this but I have to select the key as opposed to have it detect the key here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/15LlrcIUh8VnypZYMOnzXgXcqryIXTAqU-Ok3RPXbqvg/edit)

```
function getmyImage() {
var doc= DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
var selection = doc.getSelection()
var tables1 = doc.getBody().getTables()
var table1 = tables1[0].getChild(0).asTableRow().getCell(1).getText()
var elements = selection.getRangeElements()


// Report # elements. For simplicity, assume elements are paragraphs

if (elements.length > 1) {
}
else {
  var element = elements[0].getElement();
var startOffset = elements[0].getStartOffset();      // -1 if whole element
  var endOffset = elements[0].getEndOffsetInclusive(); // -1 if whole element
  var id = element.asText().getText();       // All text from element
  // Is only part of the element selected?}


var image = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob()


var totaltables = doc.getBody().getTables().length
var tables = doc.getBody().getTables()

for( var j = 0; j < totaltables; ++j ) {
  var rows = tables[j].getNumChildren();

  for( var i = 0; i < rows; ++i ) {
    var krow = tables[j].getChild(i).asTableRow()
    var kcell = krow.getCell(1)
    var ksearch = kcell.getText()


   if (ksearch == id){ 
     var pimg = kcell.appendParagraph("").appendInlineImage(image).setHeight(400).setWidth(500) 

     }
   }
}
}}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for google docs ?https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js

Comment: Yup! Tried all of the exercises. I have added the code that I am currently using to the original question.

Comment: I have made a little progress, I have posted what I have so far in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jut an update. I have found a way to search a table if it's only a single element, but not sure how to iterate throughout all cells and all tables. Here is the new code

```
function onOpen() {
    DocumentApp.getUi()
    .createMenu("Menu ")
    .addItem("Insert Image","getMyImage")
    .addToUi()  
    }

function getMyImage() {
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

var body = doc.getBody();

var table = body.getTables();

for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
    var imageId = table[i].getChild(0).asText().getText();

    if (imageId.length == 28) {

    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(imageId);

    var image = file.getBlob();

    var link = file.getUrl();

    var appendImage = table[i].getChild(0).asTableRow().clear().appendTableCell().appendImage(image)
    .setHeight(400).setWidth(500).setLinkUrl(link);


  }}}
```